# Firestore functions onUpdate doesn't trigger with nested object change

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Google Firestore Cloud Function that triggers 'onUpdate' when a documents property is changed. This works fine for properties of type number, string, etc of the document. It does not trigger however, if my property is of type object and one of the objects properties changes.

Example data:

```js
const previousData = {id: 1, quantity: {1: 3, 2: 4}};

const newData = {id: 1, quantity: {1: 4: 2: 4}};

// updating newData.quantity[1] does not trigger onChange
```

How can I get 'onUpdate' get triggered for nested objects. What's the best practice for this usecase?

Answer (score -1):

Is 'onUpdate' function you are referring to; a Cloud Function? If so, mention it, since its confusing whether the problem you are having is on cloud function or on the website.

Comment: Yes it's a Google Cloud Function. I updated. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an answer, if you need more information to be able to answer, you should comment on the question itself.

Comment: @Joao , sorry for that, not a regular user